# make excel file merging coding python

Tags: python, excel

I try to make excel file merging coding. This is the coding as followed.

```
file_content = [sample1.xls, sample2.xls, sample3.xls]


def btncmd():

    total_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i in file_content:
        df = pd.read_excel(i)
        total_df = total_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    total_df

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    merged_excel_file = "D:/사업/발주 및 정산/정산/정산서/리빙투게더 정산서 " + datestring + ".xlsx"

    total_df.to_excel(merged_excel_file, sheet_name="sheet", index=False)

    print("생성파일:", merged_excel_file)

    wb.close()


btn = Button(frame_folder, text="클릭", command=btncmd)
btn.pack(side="left", padx=6, pady=5)
```

when i do run many time, merged_excel_file is reduplicaded. i only want save merged_excel_file which has [sample1.xls, sample2.xls, sample3.xls]  if i run many time

Comment: Remove "datestring"? If that is really a date, it will cause a new file name every day.

Comment: today i run three times, list of merged_excel_file is increased.  i only want save merged_excel_file which has [sample1.xls, sample2.xls, sample3.xls] if i run many time.merged_excel_file changed per day and i need datestring function.